# TimeMachine and localsnapshots on APFS volume

Tags: time-machine

I have a latest (GM) version of MacOS X Mojave and have an issue with TimeMachine backups. It basically stops after ~27GB of backup (my harddrive is 512GB, 200GB free). I tried to reformat backup volume but it's still the same. So I tried to dig deeper using `lsof -p`

It shows some interesting output:

```
backupd 16750 root    6r   REG   48,5      175 5232228 /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/MacBook Pro/2018-09-14-104048/Macintosh HD/.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/502/14b4/com.apple.ubiquity/com~apple~CloudDocs_A8FBF5B6-C776-4752-AEEB-064A0929F42B_xsf.framework/Versions/A/Headers/.svn/prop-base/.NSString+extras.h.svn-base.icloud
```

It seems that backup is still running, handling files from localsnapshot. I don't know however, if it really should work this way. System is creating initial backup for several hours and only 10% is done. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

.DocumentRevisions-V100 folder is a place where macOS stores previous versions of saved documents.  You can revert to a earlier version of a Pages document for example by choose File->Revert To, and you will see all the saved snapshots.

It's possible that something is wonky with a file within this folder that's causing Time Machine to stall.  If you don't use this Revert feature, then you can delete the .DocumentRevisions-V100 directory and try running Time Machine again.  (This folder will be recreated however, but there are commands which can stop it perpetually.)

[A more detailed article is here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313102/what-will-occur-if-the-documentrevisions-v100-folder-is-deleted), but the gist of it is

```
cd /
sudo rm -rf .DocumentRevisions-V100
```

Another thing you may want to check is verify your source and destination disks don't have errors (via console or fsck or disk utility)